# Inheritance annotation for nsSNPs

Tags: sequence-annotation, snp, ngs, variants

I am relatively new to SNP analysis. Is there a database to find annotation about the Mendelian inheritance of SNPs?

I have a small list of nsSNPs (non-synonymous SNPs) and I need to find how they are they passed to from parents to offspring.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a small number of genes, [OMIM](https://omim.org) is a very easy way to do this.

For example:

[image]

If you have too many to do manually, I suspect there is an easy way to query lists, although I'm not sure exactly the way myself. Perhaps someone can add a new answer if so.